# visual studio 2017 odd behaviour when debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have simple code:

```
 CommissionTierEntity tier = structure.Tiers.FirstOrDefault(x => commiossionInfo.Sum >= x.NumberFrom && commiossionInfo.Sum <= x.NumberTo);
 if (tier != null)
  {
     com.PaymentAmount = trade.PipValue * (tier.Commission / 100);
     commiossionInfo.Sum += com.PaymentAmount;
     payable = true;
  }
```

the `tier` variable is null, but still it enters to the if block
see bellow the screen shot

[image]

**Even more odd, I write to the console, a member from the null object and it is written to the console... =**

[image]

Comment: You cannot always trust what you see, the debugger isn't very reliable in VS2015 and VS2017.  You can get another opinion with Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" option.  Forces an old version of the debugging engine to be used.  Or just keep going.

Comment: Same thing.. `null` and entering inside.

Comment: Does the "com" in the code have anything to do with COM?  Beware that COM objects have thread affinity, debug expressions are executed on another thread that isn't friendly to COM objects.

Answer (score 0):

this is because probably you have a default value for a column in your database and when you use `FirstOrDefault` it try to get your row and if it can't it return default values of your column.
try use `First` insted. be aware that `First` throw exception in case of not finding a row.

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is not it. `First` also return `false`. and then the same behavior.